# Snowfall weather api

Tags: weather-api

Hi does anyone know of a snowfall / chance of snow weather api for the UK. I don't mean ski resorts but the actual chance of snow for any location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The BBC has some [RSS weather feeds](http://backstage.bbc.co.uk/data/WeatherFeeds?v=151i) as do [Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/index.html).
The BBC one is in plain English so that would take some parsing, the Yahoo! one has a code so you can tell if it's snowing, although not, I think, the percentage chance.

Answer (score 0):

[Metcheck](http://www.metcheck.com) do a [snow risk](http://www.metcheck.com/V40/UK/FREE/snowrisk.asp) report, and also have an [API](http://www.metcheck.com/V40/UK/BUSINESS/webservices.asp)